# How I can store selected drop down value and date to database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, mysqli

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link  
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/
jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript"  
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/
jquery- ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".datepicker").datepicker()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_PARSE);
$status = $_POST['status'];
$driver_name= $_POST['driver_name'];
$from=date('y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_from']));
$to=date('y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_to']));
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'punbus') or
    die("Database not connected" . mysqli_error());
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
foreach($status as $k=>$s){
    $ins = "insert into  
driver_status(driver_name,status,date_from,date_to) VALUES                   
        ('".$driver_name[$k]."','$s','$from','$to')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $ins)) {
        echo "added";
    } else {
        echo "NOT" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
}

$sel = 'select Driver_name from driver_master';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);
echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo "<th>From</th>";
echo "<th>To</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){    
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['Driver_name']
       ."<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"driver_name[]\"
 value=\"".$row['Driver_name']."\"/></td>";
 $sel1='select d_status from status';
 $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel1);
 echo "<td><select name=\"status[]\">";
 while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
       echo "<option 
 value=\"".$row1['d_status']."\">".$row1['d_status']."</option>";
  }
 echo "</select></td>";
 echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from" class="datepicker">'."
 </td>";
  echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_to" class="datepicker">'."
 </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Update"/>';
echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code i want ta save selected data from a form to database. i have 3 drop down boxes and 3 datpicker. here i used foreach loop by which i can store drop down values correctly to database but unable to save date. only date selected from last datepicker is getting stored in all 3 date fields. How can i do this. plz help me...

Comment: Did you used the same selector class ?  '.datepicker' try different selector

Comment: @Sumn2u  how to do this?

Comment: its like you might have call  the selector that you using '.datepicker' for all you should use '.datpicker1' , '.datepicker2' and '.datepicker3' for each date picker which holds the value of their respective date :)

Comment: but i used datepicker in while loop then how can i use different class for different datepicker. Plz explain it.

Comment: is counter  required?

Comment: ok you used the selector on while loop but it might contain the same class '.datepicker' so every time you pick the value it selects it for all having the same class so i was trying to say to use different selectors :)

Comment: i m newbie. So plz, can u tell how to use different selectors?

Comment: you can read from here [JQuery Selctors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) or u can simply change the class name  and for each class name call $('.classname').datepicker() :)

Comment: As i used datepicker once in while loop and while loop is repeating it according to first row Driver_name.So how can i make it use different class everytime?

Comment: it like you keep repeating the loop but the selector remains same so u need different selectors

Comment: Yes I understand. But i dont know how to use different selector and different class. Can u plz Write the code here, plz?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Dates to be selected

```
  Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker1">
  Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2">
```

This will select three different dates ! 
you can  use multiple selectors too :)

You can use multiple selectors like this

```
$("#datepicker,#datepicker1 ,#datepicker2" ).each(function(){
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: but i have to repeat datepicker thousands of time.

Comment: use multiple selectors :)

Comment: u means i have to use thousand input types and thousand selectors.

Comment: no you can use different types of selectors depending upon the cases and you can search it on the jquery selectors

Comment: i can select value from every date field but i am unable to save them. I think my problem is related to database not to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your foreach loop does, but commenting it makes the code below work.

Note: Don't replace your current code with this, create a new page and test first!

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker()
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php error_reporting(E_PARSE);
        $status = $_POST["status"];
        $driver_name= $_POST["driver_name"];
        $from = date("y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["date_from"]));
        $to = date("y-m-d", strtotime($_POST["date_to"]));
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "punbus") or die("Database not connected" . mysqli_error());
        if(isset($_POST["sub"])) {
            //foreach($status as $k => $s) {
                $ins = ("INSERT INTO driver_status(driver_name, status, date_from, date_to) " .
                        "VALUES ('" . $driver_name . "', '" . $status . "', '" . $from . "', '" . $to . "')");
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $ins)) {
                    echo "added";
                } else {
                    echo "NOT" . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            //}
        }

        $sel = "SELECT * FROM driver_master";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);
        echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "<th>From</th>";
        echo "<th>To</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Driver_name"] . 
                 "<input type='hidden' name='driver_name' value='" . $row["Driver_name"] . "'/></td>";
            $sel1 = "SELECT d_status FROM status";
            $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sel1);
            echo "<td><select name='status'>";
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row1["d_status"] . "'>" . $row1["d_status"] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='date_from' class='datepicker'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='date_to' class='datepicker'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='sub' value='Update'/>";
        echo "</form>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this query also giving same result.

Comment: CurseStacker can u help me?

Comment: without foreach it save only last drop down selection to database.I checked this code but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Now since you are fetching your values from the database and populating your td tags dynamically, you need also to put '[ ]' in front of the name of the input tags you use for your datepicker. Since you did not put it, the last is the only one that gets posted. In addition, I have done some re-factoring and formatting of the code to make it more readable. I have also taken your javascript from the head tag and put it just before the body tag.

First, you should put form collecting code between this:

```
if( isset($_POST['sub'] ) ){

}
```

This tells php to execute other code only when the submit button is clicked. Now the code in full:

```
<html>
 <head>

</head>
<body>

<?php

  error_reporting(E_PARSE);

  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'punbus') or die("Database not connected" . mysqli_error());

 if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {

    $status = $_POST['status'];

    $driver_name= $_POST['driver_name'];

    $from=date('y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_from']));

    $to=date('y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_to']));

    foreach( $status as $k=>$s ){

       $rowCount = $k+1; // for identifying the rows inserted or otherwise

       $ins = "insert into driver_status(driver_name,status,date_from,date_to) VALUES(" . $driver_name[$k] .  "," . $s . "," . $from[$k] . "," . $to[$k] . ")";

       if ( mysqli_query( $conn, $ins ) ) {

           echo "Row " . $rowCount ." added<br>";

       } else {

           echo "Row " . $rowCount . " could not be added " .  "Error : " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
       }
    }
}

$sel = 'select Driver_name from driver_master';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);

echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo "<th>From</th>";
echo "<th>To</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ){

    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['Driver_name'] . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"driver_name[]\" value=\"" . $row['Driver_name'] . "\" /></td>";

    $sel1 ='select d_status from status';

    $query1 = mysqli_query( $conn,$sel1 );

    echo "<td><select name=\"status[]\">";

    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){ 

         echo "<option value=\"".$row1['d_status']."\">".$row1['d_status']."</option>";
    }

    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="date_from[]" class="datepicker">' . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="date_to[]" class="datepicker">'. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

 echo "</table>";
 echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Update"/>';
 echo "</form>";

 ?>

 <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".datepicker").datepicker();

    });

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Once again pay attention to the [] in front of the names of the input fields used for datepicker because they are in a while loop, you must find a way of identifying them.

I could not test it on my local machine because I don't have the database where you fetch your values from. If any other challenges, let's know.

Comment: I am getting driver name from database and according to no. of driver in database datepicker repeats using while loop. $_POST['status'] is not for datepicker, it is for drop down list.

Comment: can u help me @Stephen Adelakun?

Comment: @Virender, Alright, I can now see the point. I'll post an edit very soon.